# Name for a Power Series with Binomial coefficient

Tags: power-series, binomial-coefficients

I am hoping this is a relatively simple question to answer but does the following series have an accepted name (e.g. Taylor series, Maclaurin series, etc.)

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}k a^k$$

I have a function that follows this series where a is the binomial

$$(\frac{b}{x} + c\times y^d)$$

and b, c, and d are fitted coefficients from experimental data and x and y are independent variables. I saw a previous asked question that was similar ([Why does a power series with binomial coefficients reduce to a Taylor series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3954334/why-does-a-power-series-with-binomial-coefficients-reduce-to-a-taylor-series)) but not being that familiar with these expansions wasn't sure if could refer to this as a Taylor series expansion or not.

Comment: It is the Taylor series at $a=0$ of $(1+a)^n$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, yes my mistake it should be $a^k$. I updated the original post.

Comment: Then Giulo is correct, this is just $(1+a)^n.$ If it has a name, it is "the binomial expansion."

Comment: It's not clear what you want here. This is a polynomial in $a,$ so it is also a Taylor expansion with finite terms. It is unclear what the specific value of $a$ has to do with the question.

Comment: Maybe it will help if I expand more.  The function that I derived, for n=4, takes the form of $$1 + 4(\frac{b}{x}+cy^d) + 6(\frac{b}{x}+cy^d)^2 + 4(\frac{b}{x}+c y^d)^3 + (\frac{b}{x}+cy^d)^4 $$. In this form the coefficients each binomial term (a in the original post) follow Pascal's Triangle (binomial coefficients).  I have several other functions of the same for for higher n values as well.  I am now trying to write this function in a more compact way and derived the equation in my original post and I am wondering if, in this form, what type (if any) expansion it is.

Comment: It's not clear what you want more specific than: $$\left(1+\frac bx+cy^d\right)^n$$

Comment: I am not necessarily looking for something more specific, just asking if that expansion can be described as a Taylor series expansion. I think I could it as @GiulioR suggested.