I recently stumbled upon a expression for f(x) which contains both, rth order derivatives from taylor series and binomial coefficients .
So, I was just trying to recreate the Taylor series expansion by myself by different approaches.
Then by one method, I came by a expression that looks like this:
$$f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left[ f(a) + \sum_{r=1}^n \binom{n}{r} \frac{(x-a)^r}{n^r} f^{r}(a) \right]$$
Where:

$a$ is any point about which you are expanding the function $f$,
$f(a)$ is the value of the function at $x=a$,
$\binom{n}{r}$ is the binomial coefficient,
$f^{r}(a)$ represents the $r^{th}$ derivative of function $f$ at $x=a$.

I would like to know :

Whether this formulation has been discovered or formally established by someone else before.

Any insights into the significance of this formulation, particularly its connection (if any) to Taylor series or other series expansions.

I tried it only on the function $f(x)$ = $e^x$ about the point $a=0$ and because the derivatives of $e^x$ are $e^x$ itself and at $x=a$, $f(x)$ and $f^r(x$) are just $1$, the expression was reduced to:$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$
which is indeed the correct expression for $e^x$ and I mean if you put $x=1$, the expression becomes:$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$which is literally the limit definition of $e$ since $$ e =\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$therefore it works for $f(x)=e^x$, and i tried it on $e^x$ only because of the $r^{th}$ order derivatives of it.


Can anyone please tell me if it's already formulated by someone in the past or not.

Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3954334/why-does-a-power-series-with-binomial-coefficients-reduce-to-a-taylor-series

Have you looked at that link, Daksh?

Yes, but still didn't quite the answer i was looking for, additionally I think i found something strange in that question the person asked.
Can you do me a favour and maybe visit that question and check that, I responded to that question, maybe look at it yourself and let me know if I am right or wrong.
Thanks

I'll have a look.
